# Oracle SELECT * FROM LARGE_TABLE - takes minutes to respond

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

So I have a simple table with 5 or so columns, one of which is a clob containing some JSON data.

I am running

1. `SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE`
2. `SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM < 2`
3. `SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM = 1`
4. `SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE ID=x`

I expect that any fractionally intelligent relational database would return the data immediately. We are not imposing order by/group by clauses, so why not return the data as and when you find it?

Of all the forms of SELECT statements above, only 4. returned in a sub-second manner. This is unexpected for 1-3 which are returning between 1 and 10 minutes before the query shows any responses in SQL Developer. SQL Developer has the standard SQL Array Fetch Size of 50 (JDBC Fetch size of 50 rows) so at a minimum, it is taking 1-10 minutes to return 50 rows from a simple table with no joins on a super high-performance RAC cluster backed by fancy 4-tiered EMC disk subsystem.

Explain plans show a table scan. Fine, but why should I wait 1-10 minutes for the results with rownum in the WHERE clause?

What is going on here?

Comment: What client are you using to execute the query that has the wait?  Are you sure that client is set to start displaying results before the last row is returned?  Some clients want to do silly things like get the total number of rows so they can say "displaying 1-20 of 2,047,816 rows".  Is it possible that there are a large number of empty blocks at the head of the table segment that are being scanned before rows can be returned?

Comment: Good point. I am using SQL Developer and the Fetch size (Array Fetch Size) is set to the default of 50. Even then, 50 rows should never take a minute, perhaps not even a second.

Comment: If you're using SQL Developer, that should start displaying data as soon as it is fetched.  Is it possible that there are a large number of empty blocks at the head of the table segment that are being scanned before rows can be returned?

Comment: What's the size of the CLOBs?  A CLOB can be up to 4GB, perhaps it takes time to download the data for a few large rows.

Comment: What happens when you try the FIRST_ROWS hint, e.g.

SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ * FROM BIG_TABLE

Comment: Like it or not, Oracle is the leading brand of database.  It didn't get there by being "fractionally intelligent" or worse than that.  Clearly your table has some peculiarity of structure which leads to long response times.   There are any number of possible things it could be, and you have been given several excellent hints.  What it really needs is a knowledgeable somebody - perhaps a DBA - to poke around in the table's internals.  How much time you want to spend on this depends on how often you want anything other than access path 4..

Comment: I was not having a dig at Oracle. I fully expect that I am doing something wrong, although its not obvious. Having decades of IT experience I further understand that design decisions, no matter how clever, are compromises. The question remains why it takes so long to fill a handful of rows (50) from a SQL result set.

Comment: Another think to note, the DBA's have so far been of no more help than any of the comments here. Understanding why it takes 1-10 minutes to return the rows, even when the rownum limiter is in place is absolutely necessary to be able to design better SQL queries in the future. If something does not work as expected at least we must be able to change our expectations in a logical way, beyond raw acceptance and belief. IT is not religion, faith is not required, logic prevails.

Comment: What have the DBA's done?  Unfortunately, we can guess but since we can't run queries, it's hard to say anything definitive.  I'd still guess that a large number of empty blocks at the head of the table segment would be the more likely culprit.  Particularly if this is a table that people are doing direct-path loads into.  As a first step, I'd use the `dbms_space.space_usage` procedure to get an idea about how much empty space there is in the table to see if that's plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I found the issue. ROWNUM does not operate like I thought it did and in the code above it never stops the full table scan.

This is because:

RowNum is assigned during the predicate operation (where clause evaluation) and incremented afterwards, i.e.: your row makes it into the result set and then gets rownum assigned.

In order to filter by rownum you need to already have it exist, something like ...

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE) WHERE ROWNUM < 1
```

In effect what this means is that there is no way to filter out the top 5 rows from a table without having first selected the entire table if no other filter criteria are involved.

I solved my problem like this...

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE 
  DATE_COL BETWEEN :Date1 AND :Date2) WHERE ROWNUM < :x;
```

Comment: Having additional predicates makes this a totally different question.  Your first example is incorrect: `select * from big_table where rownum = 1` works fine, excluding some weird case like those mentioned in other comments.

Comment: I am sorry to inform but it does not work fine. The response for running 3. above is 51s with the data recently cached.

The explain plan shows a full table scan, and although these sometimes lie to you, the autotrace shows 531,484 logical IO's which is consistent with the size of my table of 9711mb.

Comment: To prove my point that rownum is not working like you assume it would, try returning {select * from big_table where rownum > 1}. You will not get any results, because rownum is only assigned after the predicate operation which means it cannot be effectively used to limit the result set by itself.

Comment: There must be something special about your table or environment for #3 to run slowly.  I run statements like #3 all the time against tables that are are hundreds of GB in size, and they typically return in less than a second.

Comment: There is probably nothing special about the OP's table or hardware. Your running statements like #3 above does not make it right to do so. If you think you have a good intuition about it, try running WHERE rownum = 2 instead. Rownum is assigned AFTER the predicate is evaluated, so how is Oracle to know whether a row will in fact meet the predicate unless it has read it an evaluated it? Your assumption that you can use rownum to limit the results is wrong and it is other elements of your predicate that are providing the row-limiting performance. Use RANK OVER instead.